# Get user properties by email from SharePoint 2013 User Profile

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, user-profile

I'm getting the user email from an external HR system.

I want to retrieve the user properties from SharePoint User Profile by email using the rest API (I'm using a SharePoint-hosted app) but it seems like it's not supported. The only that I found is getting the user by his account name like the following `http://<domain>/en/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=%27domain\user%27`

When I change the accountName by email, it simply doesn't work : `http://<domain>/en/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(Email=@v)?@v=%27Email%27`

Anyone has faced the same requirement ? Anyone has another idea ?

Comment: can you add more description?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor: I've updated the question.

Comment: external HR system means? are they in different system/domain? You can  execute rest query inside your sharepoint environment only

Comment: I'm retrieving user email from a WCF web service, and I want to retrieve user's user profile from SharePoint 2013 user profile service using rest api.

Comment: ohh.. do these emails/users exist in SharePoint Site?

Comment: Yes. Users are both present in Active Directory and external HR system. SharePoint User profile synchronization is done using both AD import and BCS for retrieving additional information.

Comment: http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: @AtishDipongkor : I already took a look at all the possible blog posts and articles, that's why I'm posting the question here.

Comment: Can you share your error message? If possible come to skype. My Id: du.atish@outlook.com

Comment: @AtishDipongkor : The error says that the parameter is not valid (not supported by the request) 'message: {
lang: "en-US"
value: "The parameter name Email is not valid."
}'
That's why I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: try this end point `/_api/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser`. see example over here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008871/Developing-Custom-Date-Picker-People-Picker-and-Ch

Comment: Also show your full code in question

Comment: What all properties of user do you require to retrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use the method that you are trying. The SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getPropertiesFor Method only takes one argument and that is the *accountName*. See more info [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712745.aspx).

One endpoint that you can use however is :

```
/_api/Web/SiteUsers?$filter=Email eq '#email#'
```

where **#email#** will be **john.doe@yourdomain.com**

Hope it helps someone.